# Mocha throws unexpected token error for ES6 object spread operator

Tags: mocha.js, babeljs

When I run mocha, it abruptly interrupts with an `Unexpected token` error if I use the object spread operator in my app:

```
SyntaxError: ../app/middleware/api.js: Unexpected token (30:13)
  28 |
  29 |   // Dispatch beginning action
> 30 |   dispatch({ ...payload, type: startAction });
```

Replacing it with `Object.assign` fixes the issue. I've included the `transform-object-rest-spread` plugin in the `webpack.config.js` file like so:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['stage-2','es2015','react'],
        plugins: ['transform-class-properties', 'transform-object-rest-spread']
      }
    }]
  }
```

The app works fine in the browser, which leads me to believe that running mocha like this:

`mocha './app/tests/*.spec.js' --compilers js:babel-register --recursive`

does not include the babel plugins.

Is there a way to make it include them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your config is inside your `webpack.config.js` file, Babel will only compile files when run through Webpack. When you run your files through Mocha, Babel will run without any configuration.

You should move your config into a `.babelrc` file in your project containing:

```
{
    presets: ['stage-2','es2015','react'],
    plugins: ['transform-class-properties', 'transform-object-rest-spread']
}
```

and remove the config from your webpack config.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `babel-core/register` instead of `babel-register`.

This is how I use mocha to run my own tests and it works great:

```
find ./tests -name "*.test.js" | xargs mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register
```