# transform-class-properties plugin in React Enzyme shallow rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Enabled `transform-class-properties` plugin webpack module exports, which is helping me to have `class` which is a registered word in javascript to be used normally in my html code and transpilation step using the plugin takes on the heavy lifting.

I'm using `enzyme` for testing components now I have issue where in I have my component like this.

```
export default class Settings extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class='something'>Settings</div>
            );
    }
}
```

If I want to test in my unit test if I have any `something` class in my Component it fails always.

```
export default class Settings extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='something'>Settings</div>
            );
    }
}
```

But if I do the above transformation myself, I have UT passing.

How can I do the transformation step to kick in before unit testing too. I'm using npm script test like this
`"test": "mocha -w ./test/**/*.js  --compilers js:babel-core/register --reporter spec",`

Answer (score 0):

My bad -- The solution lies in `.bablerc` solved it using another stackoverflow thread [Mocha throws unexpected token error for ES6 object spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142972/mocha-throws-unexpected-token-error-for-es6-object-spread-operator)